# How to set customPaper for domPDF in laravel?

Tags: laravel, dompdf

This is my code in Controller. Now I want to set CustomPaper for printing because A4 size is not Portable for large width file in domPDF.

```
$category = Category::where('id',$request->category_id)->first();
$file = 'Client Ledger Report - '.date('d-m-Y').'.pdf';
$pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.reports.client_statement_report',compact('records','category','type','from','to'));
return $pdf->download($file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write custom dimension in an array variable and by using `setPaper()` method and chain it with `PDF::loadView()->setPaper($dimension)`.
Example:

```
$category = Category::where('id',$request->category_id)->first();

/* Custom Dimensions */
$dimension= array(0,0,680,920);

$file = 'Client Ledger Report - '.date('d-m-Y').'.pdf';
$pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.reports.client_statement_report',compact('records','category','type','from','to'))->setPaper($dimension);
return $pdf->download($file);
```

Comment: what is height and width in these values (680,920).

Comment: Height: 680 & Width: 920